# AWS Athena connectivity issue with PocketQuery through JDBC

Tags: amazon-web-services, confluence, amazon-athena

I am trying to connect `AWS Athena` through `PocketQuery` (Atlassian Confluence). Written a simple Select query, but getting the bellow issue.

> PocketQuery experienced an error! There were errors executing this
>   statement. Something must be wrong with the query or the datasource
>   connection. For inspection, please use the debug mode in the macro or
>   contact your administrator.
>
> Error Details Type: UncategorizedSQLException Message:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL  [
>   select * from database limit 10     ]

Comment: Question, does PocketQuery use a standard JDBC or ODBC driver?  I *think* that Athena might require custom drivers.

Comment: The jdbc driver provided by AWS is used <https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html>-@Zerodf